# How can I Binding for Items source using object?

Tags: class, xaml, xamarin

I can't Binding.
and show data  Object such as MyProject.Models.Class

```
`XAML
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding City}" x:Name="selectCity" />`
`C#`
`List<AddInfo> addInfo = new List<AddInfo>`
      `  {
            new Class{City ="West Amman" },
            new Class{City ="East Amman" },
            new Class{City ="Ajloun" }
        };`  
`MyProject.Model.Class`    
`public class Class{
public string City { get; set; }
}` 
`Output` 
`MyProject.Model.Class
MyProject.Model.Class
MyProject.Model.Class`
```

Comment: Have you problem been solved?

Answer (score 1):

XAML

```
<Picker x:Name="picker" Title="Select Country" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" >
</Picker>
```

Use this in your view model

C#

```
public partial class SamplePage: ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Country> CountryList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Country>
    {
        new Country{Name = "India" },
        new Country{Name = "Australia" },
        new Country{Name = "UAE" },
        new Country{Name = "USA" },
    };

    public SamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picker.ItemsSource = CountryList;
    }
}
```

Country class

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @OmarMohammad try now

Comment: if you tell how can I access to text from class better

Comment: take value from new Class{City ="===> Ajloun <===" }

Comment: you need to use ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" in xaml

Comment: How can I use that in Listview

Comment: no not working I think have problem in update wait me check please tell me how use that in listview

Comment: You just need to wrap this picker in Listview. thats it.